# Batch file to rewrite txt file starting from last line

Tags: batch-file, cmd

lets say that i have test.txt with this lines

```
1
2
3
```

i need batch file to rewrite this file as

```
3
2
1
```

in new txt file

i tried this to copy last line

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in (ttt.txt) do set last=%%A
echo %last%>>ttt_lastline.txt
```

and this to delete last line

```
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set row=
for /F "delims=" %%j in (File.txt) do (
  if  defined row echo.!row!>> File.new
  set row=%%j
)
```

but wasn't helpful

Comment: How long is the file?

Comment: @Magoo it's 815 line

Comment: `powershell "$c = gc test.txt; $c[$c.length..0]" > reversed.txt` would be the easiest solution I can think of.

Comment: @rojo: What about this one-liner?: `(for /F "tokens=1*" %%b in ('set i^=1000^&(for /F "delims=" %%a in (test.txt^) do @set /A i-^=1^&echo ^ %%a^)^|sort') do @echo %%c) > reversed.txt`

Comment: So you really want to reverse a file or you want to sort it in descending order?

Comment: @Aacini, I like your one-liner, although it loses leading white-spaces...

Comment: @aschipfl: To preserve leading spaces you may insert an unused char in a `delims=c` option in first `for` and change the space in the `echo` command by the same char: `(for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%b in ('set i^=1000^&(for /F "delims=" %%a in (test.txt^) do @set /A i-^=1^&echo :%%a^)^|sort') do @echo %%c) > output.txt`

Comment: @Aacini, obviously; but if there is no unused character, it becomes way more complicated (splitting off a fixed amount of characters, so 3 here, given that `i` is initialised to a number much greater than the number of lines available in the file, and having to have delayed expansion toggling for that purpose to avoid loss of `!`, etc.). Anyway, I still do like your approach... ;-)

Comment: thanks guys for commenting there is one answer worked with me down there <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Vbscript solution.

Create a file named reverse.vbs and use this as the code.

```
Dim Stack: Set Stack = CreateObject("System.Collections.Stack")

Do While Not WScript.StdIn.AtEndofStream
    Stack.Push WScript.StdIn.ReadLine
Loop

WScript.StdOut.WriteLine Join(Stack.ToArray, vbCrLf)
```

Now to reverse your file execute this from a cmd prompt or a batch file.

```
type input.txt |cscript //nologo Reverse.vbs>>output.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=100lines.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"
SET /a count=0
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (%filename1%) DO (
 SET /a count+=1
 SET "line[!count!]=%%a"
)
(
FOR /L %%a IN (%count%,-1,1) DO ECHO(!line[%%a]!
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `100lines.txt` containing some dummy data for my testing.

Produces the file defined as %outfile%

Using `delayedexpansion`, read each line into `line[?]` using `!count!`, then simply `echo` each line loaded in reverse order.

Comment: i just tried it but nothing happen what should i do ?

Answer (score -1):

@echo off 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
for /f %%a in (forward.txt) do 
    ( 
     set reversed=%%a !reversed! 
    ) 
for %%i in (!reversed!) do echo.%%i >> reversed.txt 
goto :eof